# Problem with numbering of questions in exsheets

Tags: numbering, enumerate, itemize, labels, exsheets

When using :

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[points]{name=points}
\SetupExSheets[question]{name=}
    \begin{document}

    \section*{}
    \setcounter{question}{0}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Limits:
    \begin{enumerate}
       \item \includequestions[random=1]{limit1}
        \item \includequestions[random=1]{limit2}
        \item  \includequestions[random=1]{limit3}
      \end{enumerate}   

      \end{enumerate} 

    \end{document}
```

I get something like in the picture:[image]

I want to remove question labels 1, 2, 3 so I wrote :

```
\SetupExSheets[question]{name=}
```

but still question numbers remain.
How to get rid of them?
My questions are all extracted from files like :

```
{limit1.tex}

\begin{question}[type=exam,topic=easylimit]{1}
\SetQuestionProperties{cikli=I2014}
    $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^4-5x}{x^2-3x+1} \, $
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\end{solution}
```

Regards

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the heading instance `empty`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  headings=empty,
  points/name=points
}

\begin{document}

\section*{}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Limits:
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{question}
      foo
    \end{question}
    \item
    \begin{question}
      bar
    \end{question}
    \item
    \begin{question}
      baz
    \end{question}
  \end{enumerate}   
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]